# Why is my .load() not working when I try to get specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

So what I am trying to do is to get and display div tag from another aspx page to my container div.

this is the jQuery:

```
function GetDocumentInfo(url) {
    $('MyContainer').load(url + ".otherdiv");
}
```

It occurs on a click event.

I get `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND)` beacuse the the url becomes: `http://local/testing.aspx.otherdiv`

Is it beacuse its a aspx page and not a html page?

If I change the code to  `$('MyContainer').load(url);` it works! but the whole page gets rendered :P But I want a specific div container to get displayed not the whole page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a space there after the url:

```
$('MyContainer').load(url + " .otherdiv");
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi you just need too change

```
$('MyContainer').load(url + ".otherdiv");
```

to this :

```
$('MyContainer').load(url, " .otherdiv");
```

this selceted div need to be space ;)